# allow image access only from specific html page

Tags: security, .htaccess, httprequest

I've got different users for my website, owning different images which are all stored in the same folder. The images are stored in an incremental fashion, 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc.
User can view these pictures on a specific php page. Now I want to restrict the access to these images only through this php page so that they can't simply enumerate all the filenames to see the images of other users.

I thought of doing this with an `.htaccess` file which is stored besides the images in `/shop/img/userimg/` and would look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/shop.php [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F]
```

My site is a subsite (as you can see: /shop/) and the php page to view these images would be `shop.php`.

Now, is this possible at all? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the referer header is not to be trusted. Some proxies and firewall remove the header entirely, so you have to account for it not being present (that's what the 2nd line is for)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/shop/shop\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if the referer (page request came from) does not contain shop.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/shop/shop\.php [NC]
#and it is a request for images, then send a 403 forbidden
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F,L]
```

Comment: I think you are missing a `!`. The code currently does the opposite of what beta wants.

Comment: @Gerben - Corrected above - Thanks for spotting that!